# How to use css-property in html string in Flutter?

Tags: html, css, pdf, flutter, flutter-layout

Is there any better approach to use css property in html string in flutter? It is possible via **inline** or **internal** css property but **is it possible via external css in flutter?**

```
Future<void> _printPdfAsHtml() async {
  print('Print ...');
  await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async {
    return await Printing.convertHtml(
        format: format,
        html:
            '<html><body><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table><table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table></body></html>');
  });
}
```

Comment: no you can not use external css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Use Inline `CSS`  OR Internal `CSS`

```
Future<void> _printPdfAsHtml() async {
  print('Print ...');
  await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async {
  return await Printing.convertHtml(
    format: format,
    html: '<html><head><style>table{ border:1px solid black;}</style></head><body><table><tr><td>somedata</td></tr></table></body></html>');
     });
  }
```

You Can also find a reference Here :https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: I want to know, How to use External CSS?

Comment: You do note user external CSS to this property. You have to use EITHER Internal CSS that i post in answer OR inline CSS.

Comment: I want to separate the styles so I have to use external css. How to do that? Isn't it possible?

Comment: @jazzbpn you can also find a reference from link given in Posted answer.

Comment: After seeing your answer, I knew it is possible via inline or internal css. But I want to keep code clean. So, is it possible via external css?

Comment: @jazzbpn According to my knowledge it's not possible in this type of html strings like making a pdf or sending a mail. in this type of code you have to use internal or inline css.

Comment: @jazzbpn i think internal CSS is best option for you. So your styling code is in separate  tag and your html code is separate too.

Comment: @Hvr, the html string will be so long so I just want to split the possible codes. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @jazzbpn Yes but this is the only way i think.

Comment: Okey, Let see. Thank you !! 